# Managing Multiple Hierarchical Rails Models Interlinked to Multiple Levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, rails-activerecord

I am building a To Do application but with multiple levels of tasks and subtasks. I have been following Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and almost everything I have learnt till now is from there.

My app has multiple hierarchy models. What I mean is that at the top is the User, a user can have multiple goals, each goal can have multiple tasks, and each task can have multiple subtasks.

Just to give you a more clear idea, I'll list down the hierarchy

- User
- Goals  (multiple goals per user)
- Tasks  (multiple tasks per goal)
- Subtasks  (multiple subtasks per task)

Now, when I created the models, I included a dependency (has_many/belongs_to) between goals and users, but I also did the same for tasks and users and subtasks and users. The reason for this is that I wanted an 'id' column in all tables that corresponds to the user table so that I can list down all subtasks/tasks/goals of a user very easily.

Coming to the front end, I need forms that are capable of adding goals/tasks/subtasks.

The relation between users and goals is not problematic at all. The has_many/belongs_to relation allows me to user something like

```
 def create
  @goal = current_user.goals.build(path_params)

   if @goal.save
     redirect_to current_user
   else
    .
    .
   end

 end
```

However, the problem arises when I have 3 levels of hierarchy. User, goals and tasks.

My question is that how exactly do I do this for the task controller?

I tried using something like

```
@task = current_user.goals.tasks.build(task_params)
```

but that has the obvious flaw apart from probably being syntactically incorrect : there is no way to detect what particular goal this task is being assigned to.

What I can think of is that the front end form must contain a field (perhaps hidden) that contains the goal ID to which the task is being assigned. But not entirely sure is this is correct as well or how if a front end gimmick like that can actually help in case there are even more levels of hierarchy.

Please tell me where I am going wrong / whats a better way to do this.

I am only a beginner right now so I am very confused on how multiple level model hierarchies are managed.

Comment: "probably being syntactically incorrect" - the syntax is just fine. It won't work, of course, but it's valid ruby. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I can think of is that the front end form must contain a field (perhaps hidden) that contains the goal ID to which the task is being assigned.

More or less. A better way is to have RESTful resources here. So you'll have this structure of nested resources:

```
# routes.rb

resources :users

resources :goals do
  resources :tasks do
    resources :subtasks
  end
end
```

This means that to create a task, you have to send a POST request to

```
/goals/1/tasks
```

This way, in your TasksController, you'll have `params[:goal_id]` and now you can do something like this:

```
class TasksController
  before_action :load_goal

  def create
    @task = @goal.tasks.build(task_params)

    ...
  end

  private

  def load_goal
    @goal ||= Goal.where(id: params[:goal_id]).first
  end
end
```

Repeat for other levels of hierarchy.

As for the propagating user_id down the line, you can do something like this:

```
class Task
  belongs_to :goal
  before_save :copy_user_id_from_parent

  def copy_user_id_from_parent
    self.user_id = goal.user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. It make a LOT of sense. Can you direct me to some material that discusses more about the technique that you suggested? Perhaps a tutorial or some documentation or even an appropriate keyword for a quick Google search

Comment: @RamIyer: sure, the main keywords are "RESTful controllers" and "nested resources".

Comment: I tested out your method. Everything works perfectly, with the only exception that there is a user_id column in my tasks table that does not get filled. I think thats necessary to segregate tasks based on users. Is that the correct way to think about this and is there a way to implement this? Also, I think its (before_action :load_goal) instead of (before_action load_goal). Let me know, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @RamIyer: yes, it's `before_action :load_goal` in the answer. :) Added a suggestion for user_id

Comment: Working beautifully! Thanks a lot! Going to try this for all the heirarchy levels now :)

Comment: JFYI, it's hIErarchy. :)